# Spring Boot 3 Error Failed to execute goal deploy "WFLYCTL0062" on Wildfly when running mvn clean install

Tags: spring-boot, jboss, wildfly

Whenever I run **mvn clean install** I get the error below and doesn't deploy to the WildFly server.

```
Failed to execute goal deploy: {"WFLYCTL0062: Composite
 operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-1" => {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"courese-api-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.\"jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet$NoBodyAsyncContextListener\".WeldInstantiator" => "Failed to start service
[ERROR]     Caused by: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error while loading class jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet$NoBodyAsyncContextListener
[ERROR]     Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet and jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet$NoBodyAsyncContextListener disagree on InnerClasses attribute"}}}}
```

Using WildFly-4.0.0.Final

Pom file is as below:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Please advise if all my dependencies are correct, I could not find any solution on stack overflow that helps.

My execution details below:

```
<executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
</executions>
```

Comment: I assume you're using WildFly 27 and Spring Boot 4?

Comment: FWIW, I meant Spring 3 not 4.

Comment: Hi @JamesR.Perkins, I am using Spring boot 3 and WildFly 27.0.1.Final server.

The Plugin version for WildFly in my POM is 4.0.0.Final.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by extending the **SpringBootServletInitializer** inside the main Application and added an override method **configure** of type **SpringApplicationBuilder**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CoureseApiAppApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CoureseApiAppApplication.class, args);
    }

    //If you need a traditional war deployment we need to extend the SpringBootServletInitializer
    //This helps us deploy war files to Jboss containers
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder springApplicationBuilder) {
        return springApplicationBuilder.sources(CoureseApiAppApplication.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<exclusion>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```

I managed this error by adding the following exclusion to spring-boot-starter-web. As shown below.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```